# setting error handling on dbconnection

Tags: php

I have my databaseconnection dbconfig. Every time I make a new PHP document I add error handling in the top (like profile.php). But isn't there a way, where I can put that error reporting on my connection, so I don't have to call it on every PHP page I make?

dbconfig.inc.php

```
<?php
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "";
    $db_name  = "test";
    // connection:
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass , $db_name);
    // tjek conenction:
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // vi kører utf-8 på connection:
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf-8");  
?>
```

profile.php

```
 <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    include 'dbconfig.inc.php';

    // Code here
    ?>
```

Comment: Ah shoot.... I can just set the profile inside the if statement of course......

Comment: The only comment you have is to delete "Best Regards" and "Every time" Jay??????? I just looked through your questions, and I will correct a couple of ',' and '.' you forgot some places. I can just give you a hint, so you can accept or disaccept them. In this comment I hope it is okay I write "Best Regards" to all people out there, who is helping eachother with programming.......

Comment: It is usual around here to edit someone elses question to improve it. It also usual to make questions as short as possible which means living out pleasantries. Is is however **not** usual to be **rude**

Comment: My question is 3 lines? Nevermind, I close the discussion here.

Comment: Sorry if I did not spell 'discussion' correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    }

    // vi kører utf-8 på connection:
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf-8");  
?>
```